# Passing nested PHP loop to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a PHP array that looks like this:

```
([NAME] => Array ( [0] => 16 [1] => 12 [2] => 4 [3] => 0 ))
([NAME2] => Array ( [0] => 19 [1] => 19 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 ))
([NAME3] => Array ( [0] => 31 [1] => 29 [2] => 2 [3] => 0 ))
```

This array is generated by PHP by pulling data from a database.
(The array is much larger than this, but for simplicity, I only included 3 records)

I really need this data to be usable in a script that generates a bar graph. For now, I only need the name and the first record. So, for example, in PHP

```
<?=$array['NAME'][0]?>
<?=$array['NAME2'][0]?>
```

would echo the information I need from each, but I'm not sure how to put that into the format I need into javascript.

This is the javascript format that I need:

```
        { tech: 'NAME', value: $array['NAME'][0] },
        { tech: 'NAME2', value: $array['NAME2'][0] },
        { tech: 'NAME3', value: $array['NAME3'][0] },
        { tech: 'NAME4', value: $array['NAME4'][0] },
        ...etc
```

Some type of loop would be preferred because the names can vary.
If it was just PHP I could do it, but I'm not too fluent in Javascript.
Could someone help me come up with a solution?

Comment: You need to generate the structure that you want in php and then echo it out in javascript using `json_encode()`.

Comment: The array already exists, it's structure is already there. I'm asking specifically about the javascript part because I don't know how to put that information into a javascript variable and use it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good news is that you don't have to know much javascript. Create your data structure as you want it in php, and then use json_encode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
<?php
        $for_chart = array();
        foreach($names as $key => $name){
           $obj = new stdClass;
           $obj->tech = $key;
           $obj->value = $name[0];
           $for_chart[] = $obj;
        }
    ?>
```

the result is:

```
[{"tech":"NAME","value":1},{"tech":"NAME2","value":5},{"tech":"NAME4","value":9}]
```

You can use it in your javascript like this:

```
<script>
    var my_names = <?=json_encode($for_chart)?>;
    alert(my_names[0].value); // alerts "1"
</script>
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2682f09fd5515b220402db9c600b70a0501a87d9

Comment: so I can use json_encode in javascript, and that will give me that result? And then how do I actually loop through it into my javascript?

Comment: No, you use json_encode in your php script. You can then use an AJAX request to get that json string. In your javascript, you'll use JSON.parse(my_php_response) to convert that into javascript arrays and objects which you can then use javascript methods on. The basic idea is that your php is server side (sending the data to your user) then the javascript is client side (the user manipulates the received data).

Comment: I'm not sure how to use AJAX for this. The only times I have used AJAX is with forms and other triggerable/clickable events - this would have to be ran every time the page was loaded.

Comment: So then I would use that array just like in javascript? E.G my_names[0][0]? I'm not sure how to loop that into the needed format

Comment: Well, you have to use it like javascript: `my_names[0].value`

Comment: I'm sorry, I usually hate to ask for this much help but Javascript really boggles me. Are you able to talk in chat so I can share with you easier what I have currently so you can see where I am going wrong?

Comment: sure. i have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106276/discussion-between-grumpycrouton-and-dgig).

Answer (score 1):

If you json_encode the array  you have, it comes out to:

```
{"NAME1":[16,12,4,0],"NAME2":[19,19,0,0],"NAME3":[31,29,2,0]}
```

which will give you a javascript object to iterate:

If you have the json object in a variable called arrayData:

```
var gridData = [];
for (var name in arrayData) {
  var rowObj = { tech: name, value: arrayData[name][0] };
  gridData.append(rowObj);
}
```

At the end of that, you will have an array of objects that should be what you're looking for in gridData.

Comment: When you say use json_encode, do you mean to use it in javascript? EX:
`var name = <?=json_encode($amtArray);?>`

Comment: I actually misunderstood your need, here. I was thinking an AJAX request, not embedded PHP.

Comment: I'm sure it will be helpful for someone in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

If you would echo it in the following format you can JSON to get the data:

[{tech: 'NAME', value: $array['NAME'][0]},{tech: 'NAME', value: $array['NAME'][0]}]

In your js you could do something like the following:

var names = $.getJSON('http://localhost/index.php?name', function(data) {});

This way you have an array in js.

Answer (score 0):

To get the javascript code just iterate over the php array an echo the json records like you want:

```
<?= foreach($array as $key => $value){
     echo "{ tech: '" .$key ."', value: '" .$value[0] ."'},";
   }
?>
```

Comment: Does this go directly into my javascript?

Comment: ahh ok not if you have an seperate .js file

Comment: but in your php file you can do this

Comment: So how can I use that in my javascript? The problem I'm having is passing any information over to javascript.
My php and javascript are in the same file.

Comment: if it is in the same file you can copy paste my code

Comment: But that doesn't solve my problem of using that data in Javascript, still not sure how to pass it

Answer (score 0):

```
//Assuming this is your array
$getArray["NAME"]   = array(16,12,4,0);
$getArray["NAME2"]  = array(19,19,0,0);
$getArray["NAME3"]  = array(31,29,2,0);
$newArray   = array();
foreach($getArray as $indKey=>$indArrVal) {
    $newArray[] = array("tech"=>$indKey, "value"=>$indArrVal[0]);
}
echo json_encode($newArray);
```

here it is, create a new array, with the required indexes and then stringify it using `json_encode`